# django not rendering custom 403 page, displays browser default instead

Tags: python-3.x, django, error-handling, django-middleware

I am trying to apply a custom `403` template to display instead of the browser default.

I have a Middelware that looks something like this:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseForbidden

class CheckUserTypeMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            allowed_types = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
            user_data = get_some_AD_values
            if user_data.get('a_key') not in allowed_types:
                return HttpResponseForbidden()
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response
```

views.py

```
def error_403(request, exception):
    return render(request, 'my_app/403.html') # I have a 404.html in the same folder as the 403 and that renders fine.
```

urls.py

```
handler403 = 'my_app.views.error_403'
```

settings.py

```
DEBUG = False

MIDDLEWARE = [
    # Default Django middlewares untouched
    'my_app.middleware.my_middleware.CheckUserTypeMiddleware',
]
```

The same process I have above worked for `404` errors, but for some reason, I cant get it to work with 403 errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returning a response here:

```
return HttpResponseForbidden()
```

This is a response in itself and would not use the `handler403`. If you want the error handling views to be used you should *raise* an exception instead:

```
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied

class CheckUserTypeMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            allowed_types = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
            user_data = get_some_AD_values
            if user_data.get('a_key') not in allowed_types:
                raise PermissionDenied() # raise an exception
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response
```